# swagger UI not reachable while running on Docker proxied through Nginx and hosted by gunicorn

Tags: python, docker, nginx, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I have a Flask (with Flask-restplus) app running locally on port 5000. When I launch the app locally and go below URL I can see the Swagger UI.

```
  http://localhost:5000/api/#
```

But when I run it behind NGINX, gunicorn and go to

```
  http://localhost:81/api/#
```

I get below error

```
  Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.
```

When I look at the chrome error I see a request being made to **http://localhost/api/swagger.json** Colud this be the problem as the NGINX container is running on port 81?

```
    $(function () {
        window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            url: "http://localhost/api/swagger.json",
            validatorUrl: "" || null,
            dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
            supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
            onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
            },
            onFailure: function(data) {
                log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");  // <<<-- This is where it breaks
            },
        });
        window.swaggerUi.load();
```

However I am able to make a postman request to my through http://localhost:81/api/centres/1 and I get expected data

After googling since last three days the options are:

- To send CORS headers on response. I dont prefer this as it is a security risk.
- To configure NGINX to redirect requests to correct url (http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/)

This is what my server config looks like

```
  server {
     listen 81;
     charset utf-8;

     # Configure NGINX to reverse proxy HTTP requests to the upstream server 
      (Gunicorn (WSGI server))
     location / {
        # Define the location of the proxy server to send the request to
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost/api http://localhost:81/api;

        # Redefine the header fields that NGINX sends to the upstream server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    }
  }
```

It still doesnt show me the swagger UI. I'm a newbie to this world of Docker, Nginx and gunicorn. How can fix this issue?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. did you get any solution for this?